# How to pass NameValueCollection in SqlCommand C#?

Tags: .net

I have a NameValueCollection with parameter. I want to pass all parameter in SqlCommand for execute Sp.
Can any one help me for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Connection String

```
//Connection String for LocalHost
    public static string SQLConnectionString = @"Data Source=Manoj;Initial Catalog=TMS;Integrated Security = true";
```

Then Create Function for Execute Command

```
    public DataSet ExecuteDataSetSP(string spName, NameValueCollection paramNameValue, Boolean withOutPara)
    {

        SqlDataAdapter daDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
        IEnumerator iEnum = default(IEnumerator);
        if (paramNameValue != null)
        {
            iEnum = paramNameValue.GetEnumerator();
        }
        // Initialize the Exception ... 
        try
        {
            // Prepare DataAdapter ... 
            daDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
            daDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = cnnConnection;
            daDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = spName;
            daDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // Pass Parameters ... 
            if (paramNameValue != null)
            {
                while (iEnum.MoveNext())
                {
                    daDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(iEnum.Current.ToString(), paramNameValue.GetValues(iEnum.Current.ToString()).GetValue(0).ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            if (withOutPara == true)
            {
                // Add output parameters ... 
                daDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@o_ErrorMesg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            }
            // Open Database Connection ... 
            cnnConnection.Open();
            // Fill the DataSet ... 
            daDataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSet);
            // Read values of Output Parameters 
            if (withOutPara == true)
            {
                // Read Values of Output Paramters and Stored into Property 
                mErrorMsg = (string)(daDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@o_ErrorMesg"].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                mErrorMsg = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Set the Exception ... 
            mException = exception;
            dsDataSet = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnnConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnnConnection.Close();
        }
        return dsDataSet;
    }


   public void ExecuteSP(string spName, NameValueCollection paramNameValue, Boolean withOutPara)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQLCommand = new SqlCommand();
        IEnumerator iEnum = default(IEnumerator);
        if (paramNameValue != null)
        {
            iEnum = paramNameValue.GetEnumerator();
        }
        try
        {
            // Prepare DataAdapter ... 
            cmdSQLCommand.Connection = cnnConnection;
            cmdSQLCommand.CommandText = spName;
            cmdSQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // Pass Parameters ... 
            if (paramNameValue != null)
            {
                while (iEnum.MoveNext())
                {
                    cmdSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(iEnum.Current.ToString(), paramNameValue.GetValues(iEnum.Current.ToString()).GetValue(0).ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            if (withOutPara == true)
            {
                // Add output parameters ... 
                cmdSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@o_ErrorMesg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            }
            // Open Database Connection ... 
            cnnConnection.Open();
            cmdSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Read values of Output Parameters 
            if (withOutPara == true)
            {
                // Read Values of Output Paramters and Stored into Property 
                mErrorMsg = (string)(cmdSQLCommand.Parameters["@o_ErrorMesg"].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                mErrorMsg = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Set the Exception ... 
            mException = exception;
            if (cnnConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnnConnection.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnnConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnnConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Call This function from Business Logic is like....

```
    public void Insert(string UserName, string Password, string Name)
    {
        NameValueCollection para = new NameValueCollection();
        para.Add("@i_UserName", UserName);
        para.Add("@i_Password", Password);
        para.Add("@i_Name", Name);
        DataAccess.DataAccess objDA = new DataAccess.DataAccess();
        objDA.ExecuteSP("usp_User_Insert", para, true);
    }
```